# Is there a redshift equivalent to extract year from this Postgres query

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a redshift equivalent to extract year from age?

```
WITH orders_shipped_at AS (
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,
            date_trunc('month',shipped_at_et) as time_pd
from orders
),
lag_lead AS (
SELECT user_id,
   time_pd,
   lag(time_pd,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, 
time_pd),
   lead(time_pd,2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, 
time_pd)
FROM orders_shipped_at
)
SELECT user_id,
   time_pd,
   lag,
   lead,
   extract(year from age(time_pd, lag))*12 + extract(month from 
(age(time_pd, lag))) lag_size,
   extract(year from age(lead, time_pd))*12 + extract(month 
from (age(lead, time_pd))) lead_size
FROM lag_lead
```

My error is this : Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift

Comment: Can you simplify your query to focus on the specific function causing the problem, or perhaps edit your question to include an explanation of what the query is attempting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AGE() is not supported. You can use DATEDIFF(). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2000-01-01', '2009-12-31') AS years;
--  years
-- -------
--      9
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1999-12-31', '2009-12-31') AS years;
--  years
-- -------
--     10
```